# Python - For loops along grid diagonals

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have a grid which is `x=np.linspace(-1,1,n); y=x`. I perform some calculation for each `x` and `y` with a `for` loop

```
for a,b in enumerate(x): 
   for c,d in enumrate(y): 
     functionstuff(x,y)
```

To save time, I only need to do the computations on the diamond within the diagonals defined between the points `(-1,0)-(0,1)-(1,0)-(0,-1)`.  So I am trying to figure out how to best do this.  So for a given `x`, I want to go from `+(1-|x|)` to `-(1-|x|)`.

So how would I go about this with adjusting the step size between the smaller `y`s (so that I am not doing `x = -1`, `y = 0` `n` times).

So I can make an `numpy.array` object to loop over:

```
for ii,x1 in enumerate(x1):

    y = np.linspace(1-np.abs(x1),-(1-np.abs(x1)),2*round((1-np.abs(x1))/dy) + 1)     
    for jj,y1 in enumerate(y):
       f[ii][jj] = DoStuff(x1,y1)
       xplot[ii][jj] = x1
       yplot[ii][jj] = y1
```

When I want to look at `plot_surface(xplot,yplot,f)`, I just get a line along a diagonal (my guess being that I had to define `xplot` and `yplot` as a zero array before looping over)

Comment: Yes.  I get that I have the same array (just helps for the understanding of what I am doing).  I don't see how I make my life easier by only having one name instead of 2.

Comment: can you give an example? I don't see the problem of preparing an array of the correct indices for the specific diagonal you need to iterate over

Comment: I updated with what I have been trying, but I still do not get a plot of my diamond area only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numpy` it helps to take [advantage of broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) when you can. In this case, you can set up a two-dimensional grid, `X` and `Y` and compute on it rather than looping over the elements of `x` and `y`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
y = x.copy()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')
Z = functionstuff(X,Y)
```

You'll find this much more computationally efficient.

If you want to restrict your domain, you can do so with masking:

```
MASK = (Y<=1+X) & (Y<=1-X) & (Y>=X-1) & (Y>=-X-1)
Z    = np.zeros(X.shape)
Z[MASK] = functionstuff(X[MASK],Y[MASK])
```

If `functionstuff = lambda x,y: exp(-(x**2+y**2)/2)`, then no masking results in this first image, and masking results in the second:

[image: No Masking]
[image: Masking]